# No funciona la relacion de entidades en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Hola quisiera saber por qué no me esta funcionando mis relaciones de tablas en una prueba que estoy haciendo en laravel. La idea es que quiero sacar los datos de un producto y el usuario que lo ingresó:

En User tengo:

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'user_id');
    }
```

en producto tengo:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'idUser');
}
```

Luego en mi prueba tengo:

```
use App\Product;

Route::get('/test', function () {

    $products=Product::all();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
       echo $product->name. "   " ;
       echo $product->price. "   ";
       echo $product->count. "   ";
       echo $product->priceTotal."   ";
       var_dump($product->user);
       echo "<br>";
    }

    die();
    return view('test');
});
```

Pero el resultado es:

```
Mesa pin pon Rectek 121.5 0 130
C:\wamp\www\pruebas\routes\web.php:65:
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[298]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty

Computador Dell inspiron 14 625 0 668.75
C:\wamp\www\pruebas\routes\web.php:65:
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[291]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

como se puede ver me está sacando un array vacío y yo tengo relacionadas las tablas

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `idProduct` int(7) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceTotal` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inventory` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`),
  KEY `categoria_id` (`idCategory`),
  KEY `fk_products` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rol` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`),
  UNIQUE KEY `usuario_unique` (`nick`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Aqui estan las tablas editadas. La tabla productos tiene un usuario_id que corresponde al usuario que va a registrar ese producto. Espero les sirva

Comment: Un producto tiene muchos usuarios ?

Comment: dejame editar la pregunta que me equivoque

Comment: Que tipo de relación planeas desarrollar? Por qué tener en ambos modelos belongsTo no es correcto

Comment: Entonces tu relación es 1 a muchos?

Comment: si un usuario ingresa muchos productos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tus modelos deberían tener la siguiente estructura:

Modelo User

```
class User extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = "idUser";
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'llave_foranea', 'llave_primaria');
    }
}
```

Modelo Product

```
class Product extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = "idProduct";
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'llave_foranea', 'owner_key');
    }
}
```

Finalmente para obtener todos los productos de un usuario escribe está consulta

```
$data = Product::with('user')->findOrFail($userId');
```

Con lo anterior traes todos los los productos cuya llave foránea user_ id sea igual al valor pasado en el método **`findOrFail`**

**EDITO**

Tienes varios errores que impiden la consulta funcione:

- Estás usando el motor `MYISAM` el cual no te va a permitir las relaciones pues no [cuenta con soporte para llaves foráneas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html), cambialo [por `INNODB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-introduction.html#:%7E:text=InnoDB%20is%20a%20general%2Dpurpose,clause%20creates%20an%20InnoDB%20table.)
- Tus llaves primarias no siguen las [convenciones de nombres de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) por eso no reconoce dicha columna

Para el caso de las llaves primarias revisa la edición que hice en los modelos

**Referencias**

- [Definición de la relación uno a muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: No me ha funcionado :(

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`id` = user_id limit 1)

Comment: BetaM ya están las tablas

Comment: Ya me dió BetaM en USER debía en public function products debía ser return $this->hasMany('App\Product');

Comment: Dale esta bien. Todo eso es para mejorar.

Comment: del código que pusiste de tus modelos?